# Adjusting aspect ratio of my wpf window using Viewbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewbox

I want to use viewbox for maintaining my wpf window's aspect ratio. i.e if i put my application on large monitor , it sholud automatically fit to that screen and if run it on my laptop it should adjust to its screen. Please help me out on this . it should be done purely on xaml wpf using view box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the problem with viewbox ?
Just wrap viewbox around you root views [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx) property to one you like. If you want different scaling you need to write your own implementation of viewbox btw.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="stackoverflowviewbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.Hello world.
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

But it is possible to write xaml so views will look nice on different resolutions without viewbox without any problems.